# How to get only one frame at a time from camera in a blocking loop in opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv, pyserial

I have a sensor that signals in the serial port and I want to capture the  frame of that very moment whenever I get this signal. The function for recieving the signal is blocking:

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port=PORT_NAME, baudrate=9600)
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print("object detected; capture a frame.")`
```

The code that I have right now (and works) is like bellow where I create a VideoCapture object at each iteration.

```py
import serial
import cv2

ser = serial.Serial(port=PORT_NAME, baudrate=9600)
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print("object detected.")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cap.release()
```

Performance-wise, making an object each time is not a wise move, and the problem with standard code like bellow is that each time `cap.read()` is called it returns the "next" frame, not the current frame that the camera is capturing at that moment:

```py
import serial
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ser = serial.Serial(port=PORT_NAME, baudrate=9600)

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print("object detected.")
    ret, frame = cap.read()

cap.release()
```

please provide me with a performant solution. Thanks in advance.

I have tried the making VideoCapture object each time but I don't think this would be the right way.

Edit: I rather not use multi-threading if possible.

Comment: Spawn a separate Thread, capture every possible frame inside a limited buffer like a queue, with its timestamp. Whenever serial data comes, return the frame closest to that serial command's timestamp and dump all other cached camera captures (empty the queue)

Comment: I've achieved something similar without needing to use a threaded consumer using `gstreamer` backend (`cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER`). set `appsink` properties to `drop=true` and `sync=false`. It was rtsp but I think it will work in the same way

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre], [help/on-topic].